# I have deleted a contact by mistake

Tags: deleted

I have deleted a contact by mistake. Please explain how I can restore the contact to the database ?

Comment: Do you mean you put them in Trash (from which they can be restored) or you Deleted Permanently (which means your only hope is that you have logging on and can manually reconstruct a contact from the log records, but this is not for the faint hearted)

Answer (score 4):

You must have permission to restore deleted contacts.  If you don't, please ask someone who does.

- Go to **Search menu >> Advanced Search**.
- Check the **Search in Trash (deleted contacts)** box.  It's near the top on the right.
- Enter the name for the person in the name field if you know it, otherwise just press **Search**.
- You should see a list of deleted contacts.  Check the box next to the deleted contact you want to restore.
- From the *Actions* drop-down that appears above the list of names, select **Restore contacts from trash**.
- Click **Restore contact(s)**.